# Get the nearest value depend on the link

Tags: php, sql

I am making the website with banks. On each page is writing the asset of this bank. I want to make banks relative to the bank that is selected depending on its asset.

If the bank's asset is $500 i want to show banks with the 490, 506, 480 assets, but i cant do it.

Because each bank has it unique id, the relative post show me only relative to one bank

```
$id = $rows['id'];
$country = $rows['country'];
$assets = $rows['assets'];
$sql="select * from tbl_blog where assets between assets - 20 and assets + 20 and country=:country and id!=:id order by id limit 5";
$data= $db->prepare($sql);
$data->execute(array(':country' => $country, ':id' => $id));
$relatives = $data->fetchAll();
```

Comment: `each bank has it unique id, but relative post show me only relative to one bank` is there an association between the assets and banks? Can you please add some schema information? This sounds more like a query question than a PHP question. Please add what DB you are using.

Comment: SQL is not a DB, SQL is used to query a "relational database management system (RDBMS)". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL Please define what DB you are using. Also based on `$rows` I'm guessing this is in a loop. You probably want to be looking at `join`s.

Comment: @user3783243 I need to show articles with banks to each bank depending on its asset. I have bank with name bank 1 and in database i have 200 more banks. if bank 1 has asset 100 i need to find what banks from this list has nearest assets to bank 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `select * from tbl_blog where assets between assets - 20 and assets + 20` will return *every row* from `tbl_blog` (that meet the WHERE criteria). For each row it is ensuring that `assets - 20 < assets < assets + 20`. Always true.

If you want to compare a banks assets to those of *another* bank, you should bind the "other" banks assets and use something like
 `select * from tbl_blog where assets between :assets - 20 and :assets + 20`